# PNG image is being rendered different in Chrome, FireFox, and Safari

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, safari, png

When I display the following PNG in chrome, safari, and firefox I am seeing differences.

http://bobcravens.com/demos/temp/logo.png

Here is a screenshot of (left to right) Chrome, Safari, FireFox (all on a Mac).

[image: Screenshot]

I am certain this is going to be something simple (and that I probably should know), but haven't been able to determine the root cause.

Thanks for any help.

Bob

Comment: is there an alpha channel on the png? Possibly safari's ignoring it/doesn't support it.

Comment: Re-Save the image, I just did this and the problem was fixed (I re-saved it in photoshop). Not sure what could cause that

Comment: @Dotmister. Interesting, I did just resave and now FireFox and Safari both render the darker version, but Chrome is still rendering the faded version: http://bobcravens.com/demos/temp/logo.png

Comment: Perhaps try re-saving in Paint or something, that will probably ignore the Gamma part of the PNG file

Comment: I finally have a working version: http://bobcravens.com/demos/temp/logo_copy2.png. I have been using Pixelmator for image editing. The previous attempts I used the normal 'file-save' feature. This last time I used the 'Export for Web' feature.

Answer (score 8):

It appears that Safari is ignoring the gAMA chunk in that PNG. By stripping out the gAMA chunk from the PNG file, I get Firefox showing the image the same as Safari in your screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

That's almost surely a gamma problem and/or an alpha channel problem.

Test your browser support here.

http://entropymine.com/jason/testbed/gamma/

http://entropymine.com/jason/testbed/pngtrans/

http://entropymine.com/jason/testbed/alphagamma/

Workaround: save your image in a "simpler" format (bmp or gif) and reexport it as png.